# Convert curl command into a working script

Tags: python-3.x, curl, python-requests

I am using an API from check-host.net to ping an website.
My issue is right now that I have no ideea how I could transform the curl command api into an working python script. I tried different approaches which I found on here but sadly none has give me the ouput I am looking for.

Working curl command:

> ```
> curl -H "Accept: application/json" \   https://check-host.net/check-tcp?host=smtp://gmail.com&max_nodes=1
> ```

the respons looks something like that:

> {   "ok":             1,   "request_id":     "29",   "permanent_link":
>   "https://check-host.net/check-report/29",   "nodes": {
>       "7f000001": ["it","Italy", "Marco"]   } }

Comment: have you tried the requests library

Comment: @JibinMathews , I did, but sadly I didn't get the proper response. Maybe I didn't use it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send a `Accept: application/json` header in your request. You can also use the [builtin json decoder](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) in requests.

```
import requests
headers={
'Accept': 'application/json'
}
r=requests.get('https://check-host.net/check-tcp?host=smtp://gmail.com&max_nodes=1',headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```

Output

```
{'nodes': {'us2.node.check-host.net': ['us', 'USA', 'New Jersey', '199.38.245.218', 'AS394625', 'OK']}, 'ok': 1, 'permanent_link': 'https://check-host.net/check-report/a462c3ck399', 'request_id': 'a462c3ck399'}
```